# Run something when timeout PHP

Tags: php, timeout

i have question,.
i have web which request to another web service.
but sometimes that web service gave slow respond.

i use SOAP to request to web service.

my question is how to run something(save to DB) when time out(about 30sec)

thank you...

i have tried `register_shutdown_function`,but the function still run even it is not timeout,..
help me..

Comment: Use ajax with js setTimeout()

Comment: @MahaDev Do you see "Javascript" anywhere in the question?

Comment: It is possible to set a timeout, but I would recommend that you use [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/), which makes things like this very easy. When asking questions you should give as much information as possible; the function that you are using, code examples, etc. It makes it easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to register a shutdown function:

**UPDATED:** should now only work, when the script is timed out.

```
function shutdown()
{
    $timedout = false;
    $errors = error_get_last();

    if( isset( $errors["type"] ) && $errors["type"] === E_ERROR ) {// E_ERROR => Fatal run-time errors.
        // if the code reaches this, it means, that a fatal error occurued
        // if you need to do this only when the script TIMEDOUT, you can check if message is "Maximum execution time....."
        $errorMessages = array( "Maximum execution time" );// check if this message is always the same on different PHP versions

        // just the solution for more than one specifif error messages to check
        foreach( $errorMessages as $errorMessage ) {
            // you maybe want to use, mb_strlen with the additional '8-bit' param
            // to avoid the mb.functions.overload
            $message = substr( $errors["message"], 0, strlen( $errorMessage ) );

            if( in_array( $message, $errorMessages ) ) {
                // timeout message occurred
                $timedout = true;
            }

        }
    }

    // we got a fatal error, probably a timeout
    if( $timedout ) {
        echo 'Script executed with success';
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump( $errors );
    }

}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

//note: this below is just my test
set_time_limit( 2 );

while( true ) {
    // do nothing
}
```

My Output:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 2 seconds exceeded in some.php on line 11
Script executed with success
```

Comment: i have tied it, the problem is, shutdown function still triggered even my code is not timeout.

Comment: @RyanArief: you're right. I've updated the answer, no it should work only when the script timedout