# register_shutdown_function returns "Invalid shutdown callback" error

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to catch an error when maximum execution time limit exceeds and display a friendly notification about this, then redirect the user. This is my how my code looks like (This is a very shortened code):

```
class ProfitAndLossController extends Controller
{
    private function shutdownFunction(){
        return response()->json(['error_message' => Lang::get('listings.file_too_large')], 403);
    }

    public function import(ImportListingRequest $request){
        $import = new ProfitAndLossImport();
        set_time_limit(30);
        register_shutdown_function($this->shutdownFunction());
        Excel::import($import, request()->file('pl'));
        return $import;
    }
}
```

This immediately gives me an error: `"register_shutdown_function(): Invalid shutdown callback '' passed"`

If I try to `dump()` something from shutdown function, it dumps it immediately and gives the same error. I also tried to register it like this:

```
register_shutdown_function([$this, 'shutdownFunction']);
```

But it gives me an error: `"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"`, but the function still does not get executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You code is very incomplete, with an invisible class, this makes it hard for anyone to give you a definite answer. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you were very close with

```
register_shutdown_function([$this, 'shutdownFunction']);
```

your issue is: the error (Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded) is being generated from method set_time_limit(30); you placed your register_shutdown_function
AFTER the timeout method has returned a fatal error. your code is never going to reach your shutdown function. you need to find another way to catch the error or do something if the time limit is reached. I suggest you look into this thread.

[Run something when timeout PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907890/run-something-when-timeout-php)

Comment: I have tried to put register_shutdown_function above the set_time_limit function, but the timeout still occurs without running my function. Also, I'm using register_shutdown_function([$this, 'shutdownFunction']); version now since it seems correct callback, but the shutdown function still does not get triggered